# Android TCP connection to an Arduino

Tags: java, android, tcp, arduino

I am trying to connect an Arduino with Android using TCP. For Android device, I am using an AVD at port 5554. When I run the TCP server in Arduino and client in Android, everything is fine. The problem is when I run a TCP server in Android and client in Arduino, the client is simply waiting for the server.

This method (in Arduino code) is actually the one which is failing:

```
if (client.connect(serverIP, serverPort))
```

I know that I should do a port forward here. I did

```
telnet localhost 5554
redir add tcp:7600:7700 //7600 specified in client program. 7600 specified as Android server port
```

Furthermore, to test the actual problem, I wrote a TCP server and client in C. And then I tried all, Audrino, C, and Android server/client combinations. Every combination except the Audrino client and Android server is working.

Where is the error?

Comment: Can you connect with pc-client to Android server?

Comment: Why are you messing around with portforwarding if you are in the same LAN?

Comment: @greenapps I can connect pc-client to android server

Comment: @greenapps: The port forwarding is required because I am using a android virtual device. Without this it wont work. And yes I am using same lan

Comment: Which is the virtual device?

Comment: @greenapps I am not sure whether this is the answer you are looking for. The device is nexus 7 running android 4.2.2, API level 17. The avd is running on port 5554.

Comment: @greenapps I have tried the entire thing in both linux and windows (using putty). The result is the same..... It simply doesnt work :(

Comment: A Nexus 7 is no virtual device. Why are you talking over an avd on a port. Where is that avd? What does that have to do with the problem? As I understand it your Ardino client cannot connect to a server on the nexus. Now you say that with windows and linux it does not worrk. Where you first said that all combinations work exept ardino-nexus. Could you be a little more to the point about a specific connection. I still do not understand what you tried with putty on linux and windows. Did you try to connect to the nexus? You did not explain where/why portforwarding is needed.

Comment: @greenapps I am using and Android virtual device....... not the actual Nexus. It runs on emulator

Comment: @greenapps: Check this. It explains why I need port forwarding http://iomem.com/archives/23-Redirecting-TCP-and-UDP-traffic-to-the-Android-emulator.html

Comment: @greenapps I ran in windows and linux means, I tried running the android virtual device (emulator) both in linux and windows

Comment: Ok. I tried to let a client on an Android device connect with a server running on an Android emulater. The server was listening on port 2000. Under windows I did a 'adb forward tcp:2000 tcp:2000'. The client could not connect either. The port on which the emulator is running is not important -I think- as with the adb command that port is not used. Would like to help you but at the moment I'm stuck. Before the adb command succeeded only one emulator could be running. The server showed as local ip addres 0.0.0.0 which is no good i think.

Comment: Thank you for spending time. the port on emulator running is required bcos I dont think you can redirect udp trafic with adb like you did above (not important now). For me the C to android is working perfectly (c server - android client and the reverse android server and c client) The problem only comes when arduino working as client and android as server.